# Which URL should be used to verify in-App purchase receipts 

Tags: iphone

I have completed an iPhone application which sells its subscription using IAP and, for that, I have took all the necessary steps and it's working fine.

I just need to know which URL I should used to verify receipts on the server side?

When I was developing the application and testing IAP I was using:

> "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"

Now I have submitted my application and IAP for review, on which environment will Apple test my IAP? Do I need to change the URL to:

> "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"

Answer (score 3):

Look at Apple's [technotes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html), go to "FAQ" and scroll down to number 15.
it says:

> - Use the sandbox url
>     https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
>     while testing your application in the
>     sandbox and **while your application is
>     in review**.
> - Use the production url
>     https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
>     once your application is live in the
>     App Store.

Comment: Isn't it https for the production url?

Answer (score 1):

The way Mugunth Kumar did it in his MKStoreKit was:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define kReceiptValidationURL @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
#else
#define kReceiptValidationURL @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
#endif
```

and that's always worked for me.  I do that on my app side.

UPDATE:

But here is the actual correct answer from that same Tech Note TN2259 found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html):

> ```
> How do I verify my receipt (iOS)?
> Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify
> with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this
> approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your
> application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the
> App Store.
>
> Note: The 21007 status code indicates that this receipt is a sandbox receipt,
> but it was sent to the production service for verification.
> ```

So the right way to do it is to always check the receipt at the live URL first, if you get back a status code of 21007, check it again against the sandbox url.  Then you'll know if it was verified or not and if it was verified in the live server or in the sandbox.  We send the receipt to our server and this check is done from there, which keeps the user from using a redirection exploit.  Then our server sends a secret back to the app if it checks out and records the transaction in a database.  Also from here we can track how many hack attempts are happening each day.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, as @Mark mentioned above, the documentation is incorrect or outdated - I filed a bug report to Apple.

The production URL is with https.

`https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`.

You may verify the URL by just requesting it, it should return a JSON string like

`{"status":21000}`

*Cost me two expedited reviews ;)*